# Подставление своих значений в поля ForeignKey для ModelForm Django

Tags: python, django, forms, foreign-key

Столкнулся с проблемой вывода человекопонятных значений из ForeignKey через форму ModelForm. ForeignKey выводятся в том виде, как Джанго достает их из таблицы модели Order, например как "*Car object(3)*" (в Order хранится ссылка на запись таблицы Car) / "*Client object(4)*" (в Order хранится ссылка на запись таблицы Client), а для удобства было бы неплохо видеть человекопонятные значение имен этих объектов, которые берутся из соответствующей модели Car/Client.

В Django модели в **models.py** выглядят так:

```
 class Client(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    lasttname = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    dob = models.DateField
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone = models.BigIntegerField
    email = models.EmailField

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'clients'
        # ordering = ["lastname"]

class Car(models.Model):
     YEAR_CHOICES = []
     for r in range(1980, (datetime.now().year+1)):
            YEAR_CHOICES.append((r, r))
    maker = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    year = models.IntegerField(
        ('year'), choices=YEAR_CHOICES, default=datetime.now().year)
    vin = models.CharField(max_length=17)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'cars'


class Order(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    note = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'orders'
```

Часть **views.py**, которая ответственна за работу формы выглядит так:

```
def index(request):
    full_order_list = Order.objects.all()
    full_car_list = Car.objects.values()
    full_clients_list = Client.objects.values()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddNewOrderForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_order = form.save()

    else:
        form = AddNewOrderForm

    template = loader.get_template('index.html')
    context = {
        'full_order_list': full_order_list,
        'full_car_list': full_car_list,
        'full_clients_list': full_clients_list,
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

А **index.html** вставка формы выглядит классически:

```
<form action="" method='post'>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table>
        {{ form.as_table }}
        </table>
        <input type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
```

Самая главная часть - **forms.py**. Тут есть некоторые моменты, которые нужно уточнить. Я пытался сделать костыль, чтобы пользователю выводились значения из смежных таблиц Car и Client (см. закомментированные 2 строки после `class AddNewOrderForm(forms.ModelForm):` и строки в тройных апострофах в самом конце. Это взял из общедоступных туториалов по `forms.Form` и это не работает для `forms.ModelForm` Получалось красиво, но система не работала, выдает ошибку, что для добавления новой записи требуется Car object / Clieте Object, а не абстрактные id в виде int.

```
clientsOptions = []
carsOptions = []
templist = []
full_clients_list = Client.objects.values()
for client in full_clients_list:
    templist.append(client["id"])
    templist.append(str(client["firstname"]+" "+client["lasttname"]))
    clientsOptions.append(templist)
    templist = []

full_car_list = Car.objects.values()
for car in full_car_list:
    templist.append(car["id"])
    templist.append(str(car["maker"]+" "+car["model"]))
    carsOptions.append(templist)
    templist = []


class AddNewOrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    #car = forms.ChoiceField(choices=carsOptions, required=True)
    #customer = forms.ChoiceField(choices=clientsOptions, required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'car': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'table table-sm', 'size': '3'}),
            'customer': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'table table-sm', 'size': '3'}),
            'note': forms.Textarea(attrs={'size': '60', 'placeholder': 'What happened?'})
        }


'''
    car = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'table table-sm', 'size': '3'}),
 choices=carsOptions, required=True)
    customer = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'table table-sm', 'size': '3'}),
 choices=clientsOptions, required=True)
    notes = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(
        attrs={'size': '60', 'placeholder': 'What happened?'}))
'''
```

---

Что имеем на данный момент:

1. Форма работает - добавляет записи в таблицу Order с ForeignKey
2. Но выглядит это вот так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. А должно выглядеть вот так и при этом - работать: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Для того, чтобы получить понятные имена объектов при выводе в админке и других местах, вам нужно добавить в модели метод [`__str__()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#str):

```
class Client(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    lasttname = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    # Остальные поля

    def __str__(self):
        # Здесь возвращаем строку с именем и фамилией
        return '{0} {1}'.format(self.firstname, self.lasttname)
```

Comment: cпасибо за идею, это сработало!

Уточню, функция заработала в таком виде: 

    `def __str__(self):
        
        return '{0} {1}'.format(self.firstname, self.lasttname)`

Comment: @overdd да, точно, я забыл `self`. Спасибо.